# How to open big files in windows?

Tags: database, windows-10

I have to search and replace a text in a 2.5 GB database dump.

But notepad++ and editor can't open the file, because it is too big.

I have 16 GB RAM.

I've tried EmEditor, but it crashes on 1659 MB

Comment: You don't "open" dumps - you import them. But how to do that completely depends on the database product you are using (and the type of dump you have). For Postgres you would use `pg_restore`, for Oracle you would use `impdp` ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I need to open the dump though, so I can search and replace a text, as seen in my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally managed to open the file by using a hex editor (HxD).